# Positioning a tool tip in regard of SVG element top position

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, getboundingclientrect

I am stuck with this one:
I got this Raphael-generated SVG graphic with over 300 polygons. I want to display a tooltip while hovering a polygon. I'd like the tooltip to be positioned alongside the hovered path.
So far, so good... I can use the .pageX and .pageY properties.
Now, this is where I'm stuck now...
I don't exactly want the tooltip to be positioned where the mouse enters, but aligned with the top of the polygon, regardless of where mouse enters.

[image]

I obviously made some research before posting this and it came up that .getBoundingClientRect() method could be what I need. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. Console returns "Cannot read propery 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined.

I am not so good with javascript, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

And here's the code:

```js
var rsr = Raphael('rsr', '147.99', '151');
var shapes = [];

var path_a = rsr.path("M 59.288,50.5 44.58,25.5 59.288,0.5 88.703,0.5 103.41,25.5 88.703,50.5 z");
path_a.data('id', 'path_a');

var path_b = rsr.path("M 103.288,75.5 88.58,50.5 103.288,25.5 132.703,25.5 147.41,50.5 132.703,75.5 z");
path_b.data('id', 'path_b');

var path_c = rsr.path("M 59.288,100.5 44.58,75.5 59.288,50.5 88.703,50.5 103.41,75.5 88.703,100.5 z");
path_c.data('id', 'path_c');

var path_d = rsr.path("M 15.288,75.5 0.58,50.5 15.288,25.5 44.703,25.5 59.41,50.5 44.703,75.5 z");
path_d.data('id', 'path_d');

var path_e = rsr.path("M 103.288,125.5 88.58,100.5 103.288,75.5 132.703,75.5 147.41,100.5 132.703,125.5 z");
path_e.data('id', 'path_e');

var path_f = rsr.path("M 59.288,150.5 44.58,125.5 59.288,100.5 88.703,100.5 103.41,125.5 88.703,150.5 z");
path_f.data('id', 'path_f');

var path_g = rsr.path("M 15.288,125.5 0.58,100.5 15.288,75.5 44.703,75.5 59.41,100.5 44.703,125.5 z");
path_g.data('id', 'path_g');

shapes.push(path_a, path_b, path_c, path_d, path_e, path_f, path_g);

for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
  shapes[i].node.setAttribute('fill', '#8c1c40');
  shapes[i].node.setAttribute('stroke', 'white');
  shapes[i].node.setAttribute('stroke-width', '1');
  shapes[i].node.style.cursor = "pointer";

  shapes[i].mouseover(function(e) {
    var posx;
    var posy;
    // var pos = shapes[i].getBoundingClientRect(); 
    // The above line returns "undefined"

    if (typeof e !== 'undefined') {
      posx = e.pageX - 300;
      posy = e.pageY - 0;
    }


    this.node.setAttribute('fill', '#888'); // 

    var box = document.getElementById('textbox');
    box.style.position = "absolute";
    box.style.left = '200px';
    box.style.top = posy + 'px';

    document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML = this.data('id');

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  shapes[i].mouseout(function(e) {
    this.node.setAttribute('fill', '#8c1c40');

    document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML = "";

  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<div id="rsr">
</div>

<div id="textbox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `target` property of the event object to get the bounding rectangle. Something like the following:

```js
var rsr = Raphael('rsr', '147.99', '151');
var shapes = [];

var path_a = rsr.path("M 59.288,50.5 44.58,25.5 59.288,0.5 88.703,0.5 103.41,25.5 88.703,50.5 z");
path_a.data('id', 'path_a');

var path_b = rsr.path("M 103.288,75.5 88.58,50.5 103.288,25.5 132.703,25.5 147.41,50.5 132.703,75.5 z");
path_b.data('id', 'path_b');

var path_c = rsr.path("M 59.288,100.5 44.58,75.5 59.288,50.5 88.703,50.5 103.41,75.5 88.703,100.5 z");
path_c.data('id', 'path_c');

var path_d = rsr.path("M 15.288,75.5 0.58,50.5 15.288,25.5 44.703,25.5 59.41,50.5 44.703,75.5 z");
path_d.data('id', 'path_d');

var path_e = rsr.path("M 103.288,125.5 88.58,100.5 103.288,75.5 132.703,75.5 147.41,100.5 132.703,125.5 z");
path_e.data('id', 'path_e');

var path_f = rsr.path("M 59.288,150.5 44.58,125.5 59.288,100.5 88.703,100.5 103.41,125.5 88.703,150.5 z");
path_f.data('id', 'path_f');

var path_g = rsr.path("M 15.288,125.5 0.58,100.5 15.288,75.5 44.703,75.5 59.41,100.5 44.703,125.5 z");
path_g.data('id', 'path_g');

shapes.push(path_a, path_b, path_c, path_d, path_e, path_f, path_g);

for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
  shapes[i].node.setAttribute('fill', '#8c1c40');
  shapes[i].node.setAttribute('stroke', 'white');
  shapes[i].node.setAttribute('stroke-width', '1');
  shapes[i].node.style.cursor = "pointer";

  shapes[i].mouseover(function(e) {
    var posx;
    var posy;
    
    var pos = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (typeof e !== 'undefined') {
      posx = e.pageX - 300;
      posy = pos.top;
    }


    this.node.setAttribute('fill', '#888'); // 

    var box = document.getElementById('textbox');
    box.style.position = "absolute";
    box.style.left = '200px';
    box.style.top = posy + 'px';

    document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML = this.data('id');

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  shapes[i].mouseout(function(e) {
    this.node.setAttribute('fill', '#8c1c40');

    document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML = "";

  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<div id="rsr">
</div>

<div id="textbox">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @FixMaker. It does work great for the simplified example I provided. However, I come up with another issue. Since graphic height is quite important, we often have to scroll up and down. And then... it becomes all messy :-( Any suggestion?

Comment: Oh I think I got it!       posy = pos.top + window.scrollY; should do the job. Thanks for your help!